# Excel Online Add in- 403 when trying to autoshow and addin using a dev tenant

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

**Update:** It seems like the XML is not the problem and the issue has to do with using a dev tenant. As far as I can tell, it behaves properly using an `Office 365 Home account`, but throws a 403 when using an `Office 365 Enterprise E3 Developer account`. Why does this throw a 403? Is there anything I can do so we can test if we can get an addin taskpane to auto show with our templates?

**Title Edit:** from "`Excel Online Add in- How to auto show taskpane`" to "`Excel Online Add in- 403 when trying to autoshow and addin using a dev tenant`"

**Original:**
I'm trying to auto show an addin following this guide: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Since the manifest we currently have in the store doesn't use
`<TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>` I'm trying to test it out using [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab)

The `<we:webextension>` xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<we:webextension xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11"
          id="{8bc018e3-f345-40d4-8f1d-97951765d531}">
    <we:reference id="WA104380862" version="1.1.0.2" store="en-US" storeType="OMEX"/>
    <we:alternateReferences/>
    <we:properties>
        <we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>
    </we:properties>
    <we:bindings/>
    <we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"/>
</we:webextension>
```

In my `<wetp:taskpane>` I've tried setting `visibility="1"` and `visibility="0"`, but neither seem to work. When it is `1` I get a 403 and this is my console

```
OsfRuntimeExcelWac.js:12 GET https://store.office.com/gatedserviceextension.aspx?=313351b2_2e0ee2d3_1500571610901&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=4 403 ()   
e5191e878673e5c7.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
  at t.n (e5191e878673e5c7.js:1)
  at new t (e5191e878673e5c7.js:1)
  at e5191e878673e5c7.js:1
MicrosoftAjax.js:5 Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
HEAD https://store.office.com/gatedserviceextension.aspx?fromAR=3&corr=41fa9016-d510-90be-877b-25c612f780bb 403 ()
MicrosoftAjax.js:5 Request to /gatedserviceextension.aspx?fromAR=3&corr=41fa9016-d510-90be-877b-25c612f780bb came back with the status code:
```

When it's 0, there is nothing unusual in the console, but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Am I just misunderstanding what this is supposed to accomplish? When `visibility="1"` it looks like it's trying to do something, but isn't allowed. Does it just mean I can't auto load Script Lab? Their manifest suggests that I can.

Any help is appreciated. We're looking at pushing a new version of our Manifest with the proper `<TaskpaneId>` to test this, but we wanted a proof of concept first.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, please see if you can make the sample here work: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin (but use 1.1.0.2 as the version, not 1.1.0.0) Also, please clarify what event causes the 403 and where do you see this? In the task pane?

Comment: I didn't realise this before, but I actually get the same 403 when I open up the *Insert Add-in* modal in Excel Online. It's from `https://store.office.com/gatedserviceextension.aspx`. The only difference is when the XML is injected and `Visibility="1"` it happens when the template opens, not that modal.

Comment: It is still not clear to me whether you have tried to make the sample work and what the outcome was.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I just tried using the Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin example, but I'm seeing the same results. 

I did change the version number to 1.1.0.2. I also tried changing the `<we:webextension>` id to `{8bc018e3-f345-40d4-8f1d-97951765d531}` (from https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/manifests/script-lab-prod.xml) and nothing was different.

I'm seeing the same 403 when the workbook loads after I upload it the app, download it after the xml is injected, and upload it to One Drive.

Comment: If I understand you, you aren't getting the 403 when you are running the sample. The sample works for you. Later, you try to upload the workbook with the embedded Script Lab to OneDrive and it is this uploading, which is not part of the sample, that causes the 403. Can you confirm this.

Comment: Yes. The sample is injecting the XML correctly from what I can see.

It's when I actually open the workbook in Excel Online and expect to see the taskpane for Script Lab appear that I see that 403 in the console and no taskpane.

Comment: (1) After you've injected the XML and downloaded the file, but before you upload it to OneDrive, can you open the file and does Script Lab open? If you haven't previously installed Script Lab on that computer, you will be prompted at this point to trust it. (2) When you upload to OneDrive and try to open there, does the Script Lab tab appear in the ribbon? (3) If you manually install Script Lab to a file (without the auto open stuff), upload the file to OneDrive and open it, does the Script Lab tab appear in the ribbon? If so, will it open when you press the Code button in the Script Lab tab?

Comment: 1) Yes, Script Lab opened
2) No
3) We're not sure what manually installing script lab to a file means

One thing that we did find out: Script lab auto shows like we want in Excel Online when uploaded to One Drive with one of our personal accounts (Office 365 Home). It's when we're using our dev accounts that it isn't working (which is a Office 365 Enterprise E3 Developer account).

Comment: Your answer to (1) means that the sample works. Your problem is that you get a 403 when opening certain files in your developer O365 tenancy. It doesn't seem that your issue has any connection to the sample and probably no connection to the fact that an add-in is configured to auto-open in the file. Please change the title of your question and please rewrite the question to make it clear that the problem appears only after the sample has successfully run and finished.

Comment: What I meant by (3) is: Open an Office file and install Script Lab from the store. Save it. Then upload it immediately to OneDrive. Do NOT use the sample web application on it. Then see if you can open it or if you get a 403. If you can open it, does the Script Lab tab appear in the ribbon? If so, will it open when you press the Code button in the Script Lab tab?

Comment: I updated the content of the question and the title.

To answer #3, on a dev account I see the 403 and nothing happens. On a personal Home account, it works as expected.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I have a developer account and I am not able to reproduce.

Comment: Is there anything you can think of in account settings or Office Online settings that could be different between our accounts and affect this?

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour in an `Office 365 Business Essentials` account. A workbook uploaded to One Drive that asks me to trust and install an add-in in Excel Online in a Home account is just giving me a 403 and no prompt in the business account.

Both the dev and business accounts have administration options, but the home account doesn't. Any chance there is a correlation between that and the error?

Comment: Could this be related to the version of Office we have? The docs for AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument say that it's supported as part of AddInCommands 1.1. The office online version we have is 16.0.8523.2650. I also tried to set the requirements for our addin to have a MinVersion of 1.1 for AddInCommands, but that failed the manifest validation.

I also see a call to https://store.office.com/appinstall/unauthenticated?cmu=en-US&assetid=WA104380843&ret=0&client=WAC_Excel&cv=16.0.8515.1000 to get the manifest of the addin, so it looks like it's trying something, but after that nothing happens.

Comment: I'll ask the product team if they have any ideas. Under the hood, there are some differences between OneDrive for Business and plain OneDrive, which might account for why you don't get the problem with the Home account. (But, again, I this does not happen to me on my developer account.) You might want to see if this happens with non-store add-ins: the manifest is deployed to a file share. You'll need to change the object passed to WebExtensionStoreReference. See here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an issue with our code and a fix is underway. It only reproed in certain variations Office 365 for business customers. I'll update my answer once I get confirmation the fix has been fully rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set

```
<we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>
```

in webextension?

Did you modify it directly?
You could try to set it by api in script Lab:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Comment: I've added that property directly to the XML in the template. I've tried on my own development manifest to use the Settings API, but didn't have luck with it.
Ideally I want to set Visibility to 1 in the XML and always show the add-in with our templates, so we wouldn't be giving the user an option to disable the auto show.